# when does a macro defined by a conditional rpm macro get expanded?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rhel5

If I have a macro defined globally as:

```
%{!?patch_file_list: %global patch_file_list %(pfl=$(mktemp -t); ls %{_topdir}/SOURCES/*.patch | sort > $pfl; echo $pfl)}
```

and use it in the `%prep` section, is it assured that `%{patch_file_list}` will contain the name of the file returned by `mktemp -t` and the file will contain the list of patch files ?

When will the macro defined by `%global patch_file_list ...` get expanded ?
when defined globally or when used first time in the `%prep` section ?

Answer (score 1):

A conditional macro expansion expands the body (i.e. Following the colon up to matching right curly brace) if the test macro is defined (note that a definition to %{nil} is a valid definition).

Macros are expanded immediately when encountered; in you case, this is when the spec file is being parsed before the %prep section is executed.

What may be confusing is that the conditional expansion defines the same macro name being tested.